# How could I create a custom tabbar similar to this

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

How could I create this custom tabbar and what does it consist of?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

On [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar&commit=Search) you can find several TabBar implementations similar to this.

Comment: That is a great resource for several controls! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 now allows to change the background image of the tabbar but this kind of custom control is much more complex.
You would basically need to write your own view and controller that would change between views, move the arrow accordingly and activate/deactivate the buttons.

As of the elements it consists of, i would say

- One background image used for every element
- The different icons in normal and selected state
- A UILabel for every element
- The blue divider
- The arrow, separate from the divider to simplify the animations...

To see how a tabbar with an indicator could be coded check out [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/TabBarAnimation) for a Twitter-like tabbar.